# How to enable debugging in Log4j using .properties file and maven?

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j, slf4j

I am trying to enable printing debugging information for a maven project. I added log4j as dependency to `pom.xml` and added `log4j.properties` as well as `log4j2.properties` with `rootloger=DEBUG, sdout` to `src/main/resources` folder.  Then in the desired class, I initiate a logger in the desired class 'org.pakage1.ClassA' and add `logger.debug()` lines but nothing was shown in my consul. When I checked `logger.isDebugEnabled()` it returns `false`

- **pom.xml**

  ```
  <dependencies>
  .....
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.25</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- **log4j.properties** and similarly log4j2

  ```
  log4j.debug=true
  log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

  log4j.appender.Stdout.threshold=debug
  log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
  log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
  log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %d [%t] %c{1} - %m%n
  ```

  and as extra step I tried adding

  ```
  log4j.logger.extendedsldnf.ExtendedSLDNFEvaluator=DEBUG
  ```

  but it also did not work.

  ```
  package package1;
  ......
  class ClassA{
      private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
      ......
      public static void main(String []args){
             logger.debug("message");
      }


  }
  ```

Knowing that I am getting warning

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

Also the project has other sub-modules that also have logging enabled similarly and debugging messages works well when stated in the `log4j.properties` file

**Is there something missing? How to check if there is something conflicting?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> added log4j.properties as well as log4j2.properties

The first one is for log4j 1, the second one is for log4j 2.
Declaring both is not a way to solve your problem.
Use only which one that matches to your actual log4j version.

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Actual
>   binding is of type
>   [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]

Indeed, the problem is rather clear : you want to use the log4J implementation as SLF4J binding **but** you have at runtime in the classpath at least one another SLF4J binding. Here is mentioned `ContextSelectorStaticBinder` from Logback that is another binding.
**You have to have in the classpath at runtime a single implementation/binding for SLF4J.**

To solve your problem, it is rather simple.
As you use Maven, I propose you to execute the `mvn dependency:tree` command from the agreggator pom of your application or if you have not agreggator pom, from the pom that packages your application.
This command will write as output the dependencies (including transitive dependencies pulled by your pom).

It will output something like that :

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ Test-Spring-Boot ---
[INFO] Test-Spring-Boot:Test-Spring-Boot:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.4.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.4.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.4.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.4.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.4.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.9:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.9:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.4.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.11:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.11:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.11:compile
[INFO]    +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.6.RELEASE:compile
```

You have just to identify from where the logback dependency is pulled.
Once having identified it, remove the dependency it if it is an  dependency explicitly declared from our own pom. 
If it is a transitive dependency, [use the exclusion dependency mechanism of Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer for me seems reasonable but one point .. why may `logger.isDbugEnabled()` returns false while the config file is explicit stating it is true?

Comment: you are welcome. Because it is the Logback configuration that is used at runtime and not the Log4J configuration.

Comment: I have just figured that out and I found additionally that if there are multiple log4j.properties files in the project or its dependency,only one of them is loaded

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use log4j appender to print slf4j logger's log, make sure that you have slf4j-log4j12 jar and remove logback jars, or it will be out of your control whether log4j or logback in use.